# VS Code Mac m1 Debug is not hitting my breakpoints with Makefile conf C language

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, makefile

#### Hello !

I'm new with using VS Code while programming in C language and I'm trying to debug my program with the "Makefile Tools" plugin but it doesn't seem to consider any of my breakpoints.

#### Config/Environment:

- Mac M1 2021, MacOS Monterey
- C programming language
- Makefile compilation (GCC)
- Run: ./binary test_file

#### Here are the steps I've done:

- First I downloaded **C/C++ IntelliSense** and **Makefile Tools** for VS Code.
- Then I configured it using the documentation, as follow:

```
{
    "makefile.extensionOutputFolder": "./.vscode",
    "makefile.configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Default",
            "makeArgs": []
        },
    ],
    "makefile.launchConfigurations": [
        {
            "cwd": "/Path/to/workdir",
            "binaryPath": "/Path/to/binary",
            "binaryArgs": [
                "/Path/to/test_file"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "C_Cpp.default.configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools"
}
```

- I selected in the tree my binary and rules:
  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL953.png)
- Finally I **build** then **run** and my breakpoint doesn't get hit.

Maybe some clues can be found in this log, I'm not sure:

```
2022-05-06 15:04:22.645419+0200 fdf[99469:2207846] [default] error finding potential wrapper bundle for node <FSNode 0x60000021c0a0> { isDir = ?, path = '/Users/julian/Documents/42/fdf' }: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10811 "kLSNotAnApplicationErr: Item needs to be an application, but is not" UserInfo={_LSLine=1579, _LSFunction=wrapperBundleNodeForWrappedNode}
```

But I've found nothing about it on the internet.

**Can someone help me with using the debug mode in VS Code ?**

Comment: You need to add a [launch configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_debug-helloworldcpp).

Comment: Apparently, the launch config file is automatically generated. My issue was solved by simply adding the -g flag in my Makefile. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you compiling with -g flag in your Makefile?

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to add this flag. It solved my issue, thanks you very much ! I would upvote you if I could.